# Broken image and display css code on screen

Tags: html, css, user-interface, azure-cdn, broken-image

I am getting the strange behavior of image to be broken and coming in green color. This issue is very rare but exist. I have verified the below information but i din't get any solution or reason of problem,

1. Open the image in new link, which opens successfully.
2. Clear cache and hit the URL again, Opens site successfully.
3. Refresh the screen by just hitting f5, keeps the issue on screen.
4. While login-in css is displaying with HTML and broken images.
5. All css are downloading with status 200 and coming from cache.
6. All images are coming from azure cdn.

[Network trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eLra.png)

[Broken Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoeEa.png)

Comment: Can you share the actual URL?

Answer (score 0):

try opening the image url location directly and see if the image is corrupted. Maybe also try to re-upload the image see if that fixes it?

Comment: I tried to open image URL in other tab and its opening fine.Images are coming from CDN and this case is rare occurring so as such no issue in image.

Comment: @MahaveerAgarwal - Ok , I am not familiar with cdn, so i wish you luck and i hope someone else can answer and help you find the cause. :)